# About archiving the message

Tags: gmail

When I archive a message(email) in my inbox, did the person belonging to that email gets any information about it?

Answer (score 5):

**No**.

The only thing that "Archive" does is remove the special *Inbox* label from the message. Certainly no notification is sent to the sender.

> [Archive messages](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/6576)
>
> Archiving removes messages from your inbox, but keeps them in your account so that you can always find them later. Archiving is like moving messages into a filing cabinet for safekeeping, rather than putting them in the trash can.
>
> **Why archive?**
>
> - Clean up your inbox by getting messages out of your way.
> - Archived messages stay in your account in case you need to find a phone number in someone’s signature or you become famous and write a memoir.
> - When you delete a message (instead of archiving), it will be automatically and permanently deleted after about 30 days.